# Need help getting the minimax function in a tictactoe game working so that the player cant win

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I have previously posted this program with another issue which was resolved, but upon further testing, I found that the function including the minimax code wasn't working, and the program only chooses the next free option for the next move, rather than the one with the best score. I am unable to figure out why the code doesn't work and was wondering if anyone can identify the problem, and perhaps provide a solution. I am relatively new to both coding and C++ so my apologies for the poor layout and the lengthy code, but I believe it is required to recreate the problem.

```
struct AiMove{
    int row, column, moveScore;
};

struct TTTcode {
    char player1 = 'X';
    char player2 = 'O';
    char computer = 'O';
    char board[3][3];
    string player1Name, player2Name;

    TTTcode() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            board[i][j] = '*';
                    }
            }
    }

    //Checks the win states using and array, there are 8 win states of 3 in a row.
    bool win() {
            int win_states[8][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, 
                                    {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            bool win = true;
            int first_r = win_states[i][0]/3, first_c = win_states[i][0] % 3;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    int r = win_states[i][j]/3, c = win_states[i][j] % 3;
                    if (board[first_r][first_c] == '*' || board[first_r][first_c] != board[r][c]) {
                    win = false;
                    }
            }
            if (win)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
    
    //Checks the game for any ties that are on the board.
    bool tie() {
            if (win())
            return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (board[i][j] == '*') {
                    return false;
                    }
            }
            }
            return true;
    }
    //prints game board
    void print() {
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i) {
            std::cout << "-----------\n";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (j) {
                std::cout << "|";
            }
            std::cout << '*';
            if (board[i][j] == '*') {
                std::cout << 3 * i + j + 1;
            } else {
                std::cout << board[i][j];
            }
            std::cout << '*';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}


    void playerMoves(char &playerNumber) {
            while(true) {
                    cout << "Please enter a position number: ";
                    int position;
                    cin >> position;
                    int rowNo = (position - 1)/3;
                    int colNo = (position - 1)%3;
                    if(position >= 1 && position <= 9 && board[rowNo][colNo] == '*') {
                            board[rowNo][colNo] = playerNumber;
                            break;
                    } else {cout << "please enter a valid and empty position: " << endl;}
            }

    }

    void performMove() {
            AiMove bestMove = getBestMove(computer);
            board[bestMove.row][bestMove.column] = computer;
    }

    AiMove getBestMove(char player) {
            AiMove bestMove;

            if (win()) {
                    if (computer) {
                    bestMove.moveScore = -1;
            } else {
                    bestMove.moveScore = 1;
            }
                    return bestMove;
            }
            else if (tie()) {
            bestMove.moveScore = 0;
            return bestMove;
            }

            vector<AiMove> moveList;

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            if(board[i][j] == '*') {
                                    AiMove TestMove;
                                    TestMove.row = i;
                                    TestMove.column = j;
                                    board[i][j] = player;

                                    if(player == computer) {
                                            TestMove.moveScore = getBestMove(player1).moveScore;
                                    } else {
                                            TestMove.moveScore = getBestMove(computer).moveScore;
                                    }
                                    moveList.push_back(TestMove);
                                    board[i][j] = '*';
                            }
                    }
            }

           int _bestMove = 0;
           if(player == computer) {
                   int bestScore = -100000;
                   for(int i = 0; i < moveList.size(); i++) {
                           if(moveList[i].moveScore > bestScore) {
                                   _bestMove = i;
                                   bestScore = moveList[i].moveScore;
                           }
                   }
           } else {
                   int bestScore = 100000;
                   for(int i = 0; i < moveList.size(); i++) {
                           if(moveList[i].moveScore < bestScore) {
                                   _bestMove = i;
                                   bestScore = moveList[i].moveScore;
                           }
                   }
           }

           return moveList[_bestMove];
    }

    void singlePlayer() {
            cout << "Enter the player name: ";
            cin >> player1Name;
            print();
            while(true) {
                    //player 1 makes a move
                    cout << player1Name <<"'s Turn to play" << endl;
                    playerMoves(player1);
                    print();
                    if(win()) {
                            cout << player1Name << " has won!" << endl;
                            return;
                    } else if(tie()) {
                            cout << "The match was a draw!" << endl;
                            return;
                    }
                    cout <<"CPU's Turn to play" << endl;
                    performMove();
                    print();
                    if(win()) {
                            cout << "You lose!" << endl;
                            return;
                    } else if(tie()) {
                            cout << "The match was a draw!" << endl;
                            return;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugger?

Comment: The player can't win. No one can. The only winning move is not to play. [Don't they teach the classics anymore?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)

Comment: `if(player = computer)` does an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: sorry about that, that was a mistake when copying the code in, and I have fixed it. Also, I would prefer it if I got some real answers, but I don't mind, to be honest.

Comment: The best way to get the most real answers is to debug your own programs, rather than waiting for someone else to find this and have enough time to read/test/analyse it all for you.

Comment: yeah, like i said I am very new to programming so i am trying to learn about debugging, but I was more speaking towards the sarcastic comments.

Comment: `if (win) return true; return false;` which is in the function  `win()` is redundant. Just `return win;`.